# Sql order by date doesn't work in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this syntax SQL below:

```
SELECT * FROM products_validity WHERE type = 'milk' order by date sac
```

My row called 'date' is 'DATETIME' and records that are saved within this line follow this format:

> day / month / year

And I'm having a problem, in my case he is adjusting according to the 'day', instead of doing a complete analysis of data, eg:

```
09/09/1234 
10/10/2016 
20/09/2014 
23/08/2014
```

How to fix this error, causing the sql can order the correct way?

**EDIT**

My Table is in this format:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products_validity
    (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
     product VARCHAR, 
     type VARCHAR, 
     date DATETIME,
     desc VARCHAR, 
     show VARCHER
```

Comment: Please show the definition of the table.  I don't believe the column is really stored as a date.

Comment: _relying for the day_ what does that mean?

Comment: In the 4th row, what month is 23? Are you sure it's not `month/day/year`?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I change the format...

Comment: Why do you think it's ordering just by the day? `9, 10, 9` is not ordered by day.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Barmar, I need to find a way to fix that arrange by year, then month, then by day, how I can do this?

Comment: That's what `ORDER BY date` should do.

Comment: Do you think you could fix all the typos in your question? You should cut and paste the actual code, because when you retype it you may be obscuring the problem. For instance, `order by date sac` is not valid, and there's no `VARCHER` type.

Comment: Well, I`m not understand why the sql is doing this, except that the syntax means the date format in English, because I am using the format of Brazil, have a problem? @Barmar

Comment: There's no DATETIME type in SQLite, so it's probably treating the values as strings, giving you text ordering.

Comment: In that case, you should store your date in ISO format: YYYY-MM-DD. When these are ordered as strings, it's the same as the date order.

Comment: Ok ''There's no DATETIME type in SQLite''... I'll try to put my values in format  YYYY-MM-DD, thanks everyone!